# Internet Not Working After Rebooting Computer

Tags: networking, internet, google-chrome

so basically, I downloaded an audio driver because my speakers were really quiet and I wanted to see if it would fix it. It wanted me to do a reboot, so I did. And that's where everything went wrong.

I booted my computer back up, it went to a black screen and said a bunch of crap, which kindof confused me, but it eventually started like normal. I went to google chrome and typed youtube.com so I could test if the audio drivers fixed my problem, and google chrome replied with a very welcoming "This Webpage Is Not Available"! So, I found network settings, and found that I had no connections in my network settings. I came to this computer, my family's computer, and looked up my problem. The first thing I found was a solution that said to go delete some things from /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules then reboot, and it said that the file would detect my ethernet and automatically put back what is supposed to be there. Sadly, instead of doing that, it simply left that blank, so i'm sure I messed up even more by doing that. Then, on another solution, it said to go to .etc/init.d/apache2/httpd.conf and add Servername localhost to it. That didn't work either. Now i'm here.

It's running 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It's a gateway PC which originally had Windows Vista on it. (Not sure if that information will help you at all, but may as well give you it anyway)

Sorry for such a long post, thanks for reading my problem, and I hope someone can give me an answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Wifi not working

1). Run Terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

2). Paste the commands into Terminal one at a time using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy from your browser then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste in to Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and finally

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I actually am not trying to connect to wifi. I use ethernet on that computer. And also, the sudo apt-get install commands won't work, it says unable to fetch some archives, which may be because the system as a whole can't connect to the internet.